# What happens when you kill a process that's installing an msi?

Tags: process, windows-installer

I have a GUI "master installer" program that starts several processes that each install an MSI. I would like to implement a cancel button, that when clicked, kills the currently running process/msi.

What happens when you kill a process that's installing an msi? Do the registry entries and files that have been created get left behind?